# load an image after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<button>` with the `rel="example.jpg"`. I want the button to load the image in my `#area` DIV, just **after** clicking on it, not with the page load. So I use this code and everything is done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    var imgUrl = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
});
});

<button rel="example.jpg">Click Me</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/x3QdU/) is its jsfiddle.

Now I found that the `rel` is not valid for the `<button>`.

I'm interested to know other solutions to do this, such as using jquery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button data-rel="example.jpg">Click Me</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<button rel=
```

to

```
<button data-rel=
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3QdU/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
  });
});

<button data-rel="example.jpg">Click Me</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3QdU/4/