# JS load image on click only

Tags: javascript, load, captcha

I need a function in JS to load an image on click only.
I use an API and if i load a captcha image every page load after a few requests bans me because not all visitors enter captcha.

O i have http://site.tld/?captcha_image=3382894 wich if i load every time page loads i got banned for flood.

So i need something when visitor uses api let's say it appears a text with "Click here to enter captcha", then when it clicks the image is loaded.

I don't know JS at all, i appreciate any help...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-rel="http://www.lemis.com/grog/Photos/20110726/big/capcha.gif">Click</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483689/load-an-image-after-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Thanks so much Keerthi, you saved my life. (and my website)

Comment: No problem. Please mark as an answer so that it'll help others too.